# I want to see where is the error in this proof

Tags: proof-verification, logic

In a proof by contradiction of a specific statement $P$ we have the following steps:

The proof began with the assumption that $P$ was false, that is that $-P$ was true, and from this we deduced $C$ and $-C$ for some case $C$.

By this way the steps of the proof are all valid for every other similar statement $Q$ even it was true.

My **solution**:

In the first line of the proof we suppose $- $P is true, that is we assume $P$ is false. But if $P$ is **really true** then this contradicts our assumption that $P$ is false. But we haven’t yet proved $P$ to be true, so the contradiction is not obvious.

I want to see where is the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can derive a contradiction from any statement $Q$, your other hypotheses are inconsistent and you can derive anything by following this process.